# About a guy wearing feminine clothing

Tags: sin

One of my brothers loves to dress as a girl. He was pranked and bullied into trying girly clothes. He wore girls clothing inside our house.
He even wears jewellery and wigs and tries to speak in a girls voice. He wants to change his name to a girl.
Is he committing zina and is there a punishment for him according to shariah law?

Comment: He wants to have set reassignment surgery and suffers from gender confusiom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [he likes to dress up as a woman](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/81994)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, he is **not committing** *Zina*. *Zina* is defined as something else in Islam.
*Zina* is basically a relation between a girl and boy before marriage. It has nothing to do with wearing clothes of other genders.

Now, let's come to point.
In Islam, it's strictly prohibited for a boy to be dressed like a girl and for a girl to be dressed like a boy. It spoils the uniqueness of girls and boys.

*https://islamqa.info/en/answers/81994/he-likes-to-imitate-women*

It's a ruling (*fatwa*) from ***Islamqa*** regarding this issue. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is absolutely not Zina. Zina is the sexual relationship between someone you are not married to.

Although he is not doing Zina but still he is committing sin, as it was narrated that Abu Hurayrah said: The Messenger of Allaah (PBUH) cursed the man who wears women’s clothing and the woman who wears men’s clothing. *Narrated by Abu Dawood (4098) and classed as saheeh by al-Nawawi in al-Majmoo’ (4/469) and by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, he is not really committing zina, because zina is the act of fornication and adultery. The sin that he IS committing however is physically imitating women (by changing the way he was created), and wearing gold because men are not allowed to wear gold in the Earth world, the Dunya, which is what he is ignoring because he is wearing jewelry. InShaAllah, he won’t commit these sins any longer, and Allah knows best.